# How do I change the way dates are displayed in channel forms and remove the time

Tags: date-format

I need to change the way the date displays on the front end, specifically in channel form date fields.

Currently it’s

```
18-2-16 2:11 PM
```

I’d be OK with this if it just didn’t have the time displayed. It’s really unhelpful to have the time displayed here, and all of the users so far that have used the system we’ve built have been confused by this.

The field is asking for a date, but the current time is appended, unnecessarily.

Is there some way to change the field to display more like:

```
Wednesday, 3 February 2016
```

or at least just remove the time?

Just to clarify I am not trying to use the date format output tag:

```
{my_date format=""}
```

as this OUTPUTS the date only

I am trying to change the way the native date picker INSERTS the date to a channel form field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of doing this is to modify the jQuery init settings for the date-picker functionality. EE modifies their scripts to coincide with the EE date variable formatting. I guess you could open up your `/themes/ee/asset/javascript/compressed/cp/date_picker.js` file and at the end of `line 46`after the `var n=EE.date.date_format;`, you could add `n="%l, %j %F %Y";`. Keep in mind, I don't know what other ramifications this might cause. This formats the date/time object for that field though.